# [42000][1064] SQL Error: Can't execute new table in DataGrip.

Tags: mysql, datagrip

```
create table Users
(
    AttendeeID varchar not null,
    FRAG boolean null,
    FirstName string null,
    LastName string null,
    BadgeName varchar null,
    BadgeNumber int not null,
    DateOfBirth date null,
    EmailAddress int not null,
    Password password null,
    PrivacyPolicy boolean null,
    TermsConditions boolean null
);

create unique index Users_AttendeeID_uindex
   on Users (AttendeeID);

create unique index Users_BadgeNumber_uindex
    on Users (BadgeNumber);

create unique index Users_EmailAddress_uindex
   on Users (EmailAddress);

alter table Users
    add constraint Users_pk
        primary key (AttendeeID);
```

So, I am learning databases and I'm using Datagrip for my dbms, but when I tried to execute this I received the error that follows:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null,
>       FRAG boolean null,
>       FirstName string null,
>       LastName string null,
>       Ba' at line 3.

Originally the code read not null, so I changed it to null not understanding what the problem was. I haven't found the answer in previous questions, any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify length for VARCHAR: VARCHAR(255) for example. In addition, MySQL does not have BOOLEAN data type. You can use TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED instead and store 1 for true & 0 for false. Or you can use ENUM.

Comment: [BOOLEAN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) is an alias for TINYINT however its not really a problem. Recommend making one on the unique indexes the primary key for the table, probably `AttendeeID`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: By the way, DataGrip should highlight your syntax errors before you run the query: https://pp.userapi.com/Xw-zJsCkPNdkoOqG8Ex4Lx_bdoCat3yW22J6Sg/tlm-72vgzo0.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar` need to have a specified length like `varchar(30)` for 30 characters.

`string` isn't a type, use `varchar(LENGTH)`.

`password` isn't a type, use `varbinary(LENGTH)` as I assume you doing the right thing and using a salted hash.

Comment: Thank you! and I'm working with a programming but he couldn't see what I was doing cause I was just texting him. But thank you cause now I don't have to wait 3 hours for him to get home to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I'll write it as I see:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    AttendeeID CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FRAG ENUM('n', 'y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    FirstName CHAR(50) NULL,
    LastName CHAR(50) NULL,
    BadgeName CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    BadgeNumber CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth DATE NULL,
    EmailAddress CHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    Password CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PrivacyPolicy ENUM('n', 'y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    TermsConditions ENUM('n', 'y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    PRIMARY KEY (`AttendeeID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `Users_EmailAddress_uindex` (`EmailAddress`),
    UNIQUE KEY `Users_BadgeNumber_uindex` (`BadgeNumber`)
);
```

I use `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` for performance, cause for that case seeking for data can be mathematically easy for db engine since rows will have fixed size.

I use `ENUM` for readability - You can also in future add `not sure` as third choise. 

About size:
`TINYINT(1)` and is stored as one byte of data and `ENUM('n','y')` is also stored as 1 byte of data.

`BadgeNumber` is `CHAR` since there may be situation when numbers may start from `0` zero. Like: `0000001023423` or maybe there can be business task to enumarate guests like:  `G00001`  - so for me it's better to use `CHAR` for badge number.

Also You may have `UserBadges` table and relate it to `Users` table - what if some user may have many badges, like if he had lost old one or just for history You'll have badge for `A case` badge for `B case`.

By idea `User` and badge are different entities. So it also have to be clarified.

I'm sure such questions may force people make project more flexible from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for you information. The information is really informative and helpful. As for the BadgeNumber as far as I know from the badge numbers I've seen for this project they all start with a 1 or higher. I didn't know this information and I like it.

Comment: @SamanthaTigerlily it's like foreseeing what may possible, of course You should ask PM or Tech Lead about it. They may know best.